# Generating intermediate vertices

Tags: java, graph, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory, theory

I have a path say [vertex4, vertex5, vertex7, vertex8] starting at vertex 4, ending at vertex 8. I have access to the X and Y co-ordinates of each vertex.

How would I go about generating a series of vertices in between each pair of vertices. Say for instance, vertex4 -> vertex5 I want to be able to bisect the edge so that there will be more vertices along the edge to get to 5.

So for example, if I have a max 'step' size or something of 0.1, then the path would then be:

[4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 ... and so on up to 5].

Comment: Look up the keyword **interpolation**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming each vertex is a point (X,Y) on the 2D plane and the edges are straight lines connecting them. You can easily bisect any edge on K equal parts:

Let A = (X0,Y0) and B = (X1,Y1) be the endpoints of the edge, then we can compute dX = (X1-X0)/K and dY = (Y1-Y0)/K. The intermediate points will be points of the form Pi = (X0+dX*i,Y0+dY*i) for 0 < i < K.

If you want the edges to have some specified length L, compute the length D of the edge AB using euclidian distance, and the number K of parts will be given by ceil(D/L).